# How does Postgresql Sequence Generator Work?

Tags: postgresql, sequence, sequence-generators

I have a question regarding Postgresql Sequence Generator.

For example, I have a sequence registered in my Schema, within the same schema I inserted the record an initial data  on table named "USER"  so by default it will have an ID of 1. However if I insert a data on a table named "POSTS", no data yet on the table named "POSTS" once I do an insert on the said field. will it have an id of 2?

My questions will generate the same sequence generator generate sequences globally based on the previous ID or record that has been inserted irregardless of the table?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many sequence as you wish.

You can associate a single sequence to multiple columns.

By default, when you create 2 talbes with their own columns declared as serial, you are going to create 2 separate sequences, so you will start from 1 in each table. In indipendent way.